# what is this error: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'diff'

Tags: python, sympy, differentiation

when i am trying to run this program it gives Attribute error.
I am new to python so please forgive if i miss anything.Thanks

```
import math
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy import diff
import sympy as sp

p=np.matrix([[0],[0],[0],[1]])
pdash=p
zi=Matrix(2, 1, lambda i,j: Symbol('z%d' % (i+1)))
xi=Matrix(2, 1, lambda i,j: Symbol('x%d' % (i+1)))
alphai=Matrix(2,1, lambda i,j: Symbol('a%d' % (i+1)))
thetai=Matrix(2,1, lambda i,j: Symbol('t%d' % (i+1)))
transformed=np.matrix([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]) 
def transformation_fn(zi,xi,thetai,alphai):
    ca=cos((alphai))
    sa=sin((alphai))
    ct=cos((thetai))
    st=sin((thetai))
    transformation=np.matrix([[ct,-st*ca,st*sa,xi*ct],
                               [st,ct*ca,-ct*sa,xi*st],
                               [0,sa,ca,zi],
                               [0,0,0,1]])
    return transformation

for z,x,t,a in zip(zi,xi,thetai,alphai):
    transformed=transformed*transformation_fn(z,x,t,a)
e=transformed*p
jacobian=e.diff(t1)
print jacobian
```

I also tried with a sample code if the diff() works or not it worked in this case
    import math
    import numpy as np
    from sympy import *
    from sympy import diff
    import sympy as sp

```
x, y, e1 = symbols('x y e1')
e=Matrix(2,1,lambda i,j:Symbol('e%d'%(i+1)))
I=np.matrix([[1 ,0 ],
             [0 ,1 ]])
k=I*e
print k.diff(e1)
```

Comment: It just means that there is no member method called `diff()` for `matrix` object. Plainly, you cannot do `matrix_object.diff()`

Comment: Sorry are you wanting `jacobian = np.diff(e, t1)`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Comment: @SilentMonk thanks.But is there any way that i can do the differentiation. And to add diff() worked fine with a random code to check whether it works or not.

Comment: @yoyo, read the link shared by EdChum. `numpy` object has a method `diff()`.

Comment: @silentmonk I tried but it didnt work and I think its only for number.Below is the body of the code which i mentioned earlier that worked fine                                                                                    matrices. x, y, e1 = symbols('x y e1')
e=Matrix(2,1,lambda i,j:Symbol('e%d'%(i+1)))
I=np.matrix([[1 ,0 ],
                    [0 ,1 ]])
k=I*e
print k.diff(e1)

Comment: @edchum Thanks.But its not working and i think np,diff() is only used for numbers If you can suggest any other function or other way to proceed it would be great.

Comment: it looks like sympy's diff isn't vectorised ie won't operate on the entire array, so you'd have to iterate over `e` and assign the result of `diff` to each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was said in comments, symbolic differentiation cannot be applied to a SymPy matrix object. Apply it to each entry separately. Example:

```
t1 = Symbol('t1')
jacobian = Matrix(*e.shape, lambda i,j: e[i,j].diff(t1))
```

The second line constructs a matrix of the same shape as `e`, in which the entries are the derivatives of the entries of `e` with respect to `t1`.

(You never actually defined `t1` in the code, which made the first line here necessary.)

Comment: You can also use `e.applyfunc(lambda i: diff(i, t1))`